# referencing a type constructor in ocamldoc

Tags: ocaml, ocamldoc

I'm getting `ocamldoc` warnings:

> Warning: Element MyModule.VariantName not found

when using `{!MyModule.VariantName}` in doc comments.

---

The [`ocamldoc` doc](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual029.html) says

> In this chapter, we use the word *element* to refer to any of the following parts of an OCaml source file: a type declaration, a value, a module, an exception, a module type, **a type constructor**, a record field, a class, a class type, a class method, a class value or a class inheritance clause.

and later when explaining text formatting:

> ∣ `{! string }`  insert a reference to the element named *string*. *string* must be a fully qualified element name, for example `Foo.Bar.t`. The kind of the referenced element can be forced (useful when various elements have the same qualified name) with the following syntax: `{! kind : string }` where *kind* can be `module`, `modtype`, `class`, `classtype`, `val`, `type`, `exception`, `attribute`, `method` or `section`.

Can I reference a type constructor using `{! string }`?

How do the first group of kinds of *elements* relate to the second group of kinds of elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the implementation, it looks like it is possible to refer to a variant constructor, but with a rather weird syntax: you must use the `{!typename.constrname}` syntax or, from another module, `{!Modulename.typename.constrname}`. With the code example below, that would by `{!mylist.Cons}` for example. This will generate a hyperlink, but unfortunately the text will still be `typename.constrname` and not just refer to the constructor name itself.

(I also learned that there is an "explicit" way to tell ocamldoc to which syntactic category the mentioned identifier belong, I suppose to help in some ambiguous case. So just as you could use either `{!mylist}` or `{!type:mylist}` to denote a type constructor, you can use either `{!mylist.Nil}` or `{!const:mylist.Nil}` to denote the variant constructor.)

Vocabulary note: In the type declaration

```
type 'a mylist =
| Nil
| Cons of 'a * 'a mylist
```

the names `Nil` and `Cons` are *not* called "type constructors", but only "constructors" or "variant constructors". The type constructors are the names of parametrized types (or non-parametrized, for constant type constructors) living at the type rather than the value level, `mylist` in this example.

Comment: Ah.  Thanks for explaining the terminology.  So the two pieces of documentation are not inconsistent in this regard.  I was mistakenly assuming that `MyModule.MyVariantName` was an element by the first definition.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: I had an in-depth look at how the thing works, and it appears it is actually possible.